# Displaying a confirmation after entering a Heroku command?

Tags: heroku, implementation, confirmation

I am using Heroku and normally I do commands like:

```
heroku run rake db:reset --app myapp
```

which resets my database. I have read online that Heroku didn't support all rake commands (including `db:reset`, but the article may be outdated? as it works fine for me)

However,  I have a production app and a staging app and am concerned about my late night programming, with regards to an accidental hit of db:reset on my production app.

Is there a way i could implement a prevention confirmation with a command like:

```
heroku run rake db:reset --app myapp or heroku run rake db:migrate --app myapp
```

or

```
git push production?
```

Comment: Make your own bash script that just says "will run <command> in 5..4..3..2..1" and counts down, giving you time to cancel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be very careful when running any destructive commands. Just incase use https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups to make sure you can recover data if you do accidentally drop the database.